# Sketch masked image overriding the size of entire group

Tags: sketch-app

I have an image inside this widget I'm designing. The image (outlined in blue) is increasing the height of the whole widget even though it is masked. What do?!

[image: image of mask]

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways to solve this :

1. Group the elements (select the elements and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), the group size will match the mask size :

[image]

2. Create a symbol, the result will be quite the same :

[image]

3. Way less precise, but it does the job : double click on the image, select the wanted area and crop it :

[image]
[image]

I do not recommend this last one, because it's destructive. If you change your mind, you will have to re-import the image.
Hope it helps.